# Inside of a event registered by NodeList.connect(), how to get a reference to the triggered node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, jquery-events

### Short-form question

I'm executing `dojo.query()` and applying an event handler to all of the returned nodes, using the `NodeList.onmouseenter()` function.  However, when one of those nodes triggers the event, I need to know which one it was, so I can traverse the DOM from that particular node's location.  How can I get a reference that particular node at trigger-time?

### Long-form question with full context

I am trying to adapt a jQuery-powered navigation menu ([see overview and complete source](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/drop-down-menu-jquery-css.html)) to work in a Dojo environment.  In a nutshell, the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="subnav">   <!-- This CSS class hides the <ul> on page load -->
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span></span>         <!-- CSS fills the <span> with an image -->
    </li>
    ...
```

The outermost `<ul>` tag represents the navigation menu as a whole... and the nested `<ul>` tags are where a menu item has a drop-down submenu.  Such menu items also have an `<span>` tag in there, to display an arrow image and make things easier to identify during DOM-traversing.

So, the jQuery code adds an event handler to all those `<span>` tags.  The tutorial link above uses an "`onClick`", but I plan to change that to a hover (i.e. "`onmouseenter`" and "`onmouseleave`").  Either way, the event trigger causes the hidden submenu to be diplayed with a jQuery "`slideDown`" effect (equivalent to Dojo's "`wipeIn`").

```
$("ul.topnav li span").click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show();
});
```

To get from the `<span>` to the nested `<ul>`, the event handler crawls the DOM one level up and then one level back down... starting from `$(this)`.  ***This is the part that is killing me in Dojo!***  I've tried dozens of variations, but here is my current (broken) code:

```
dojo.require("dojo.fx");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");
dojo.ready(function(){

    dojo.query("ul.topnav li span").onmouseenter(function(node) {
        node.siblings("ul.subnav").wipeIn().play();
    });

}
```

Inside of Dojo's `NodeList` event connection functions (e.g. `onmouseenter`), I can't figure out how to get a trigger-time reference to the node that was triggered.  The anonymous function I'm passing to "`onmouseenter`" takes a parameter called "`node`", but that's just my wishful thinking.  Dojo doesn't really pass such a reference.

What I need is an equivalent to the `$(this)` on the second line of the above jQuery snippet.  A reference to the particular node that was event-triggered, so that I can traverse the DOM from that particular node's location.  Is there an easy way to do this with Dojo's `NodeList` that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, the onmouseenter callback doesn't receive a node as a parameter but receives an event object instead. If this is the case you can try to:

1. Get the node through other means, (evt.currTarget or something like that, I always get confused with these...)
2. Use a forEach instead, get the references to the nodes, and do the event connection manually:

   ```
    dojo.query('blabla').forEach(function(node){
        dojo.connect(node, 'onmouseenter', function(evt){
            //node should point to wat you want now
            node.siblings("ul.subnav").wipeIn().play();
        });
    });
   ```

Comment: LONG-FORM RESOLUTION:  I'm accepting this answer, because I believe that you're on the right track, but I couldn't get either of those approaches to completely work.  For item #1, it turns out that the property you were looking for is "event.target".  However, you apparently have to convert things back and forth from vanilla JS objects to Dojo objects, and I couldn't make it work right.  For item #2, "node" wasn't visible inside the second nested function.  Maybe a scoping issue, or maybe another Dojo thing that I'm mis-diagnosing.

Comment: SHORT-FORM RESOLUTION:  I'm just giving up and using jQuery.  :)

Comment: I really, really *wanted* to like Dojo... because I planned to use the charting functionality in the DojoX package.  However, this framework's syntax and feel is just a complete mess relative to jQuery, and it turns out there are tons of free JS charting libraries out there (http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325).  The one I'm probably going with is Flot (http://code.google.com/p/flot/)... which does what I need even better than DojoX, with a cleaner API.

Comment: @Steve Perkins: I'm so sorry, my example possibly mislead you since node in #2 is a plain dom node and thus doesn't have all the fancy methods. Now that I reread your question again, IIRC, I think you can use dojo.query(the_node) to do the equivalent of jquery's `$(this)`. Just don't keep a bad taste for Dojo in the future - while dojo.query doesn't have the same power as Jquery, the framework as a whole is actually very intuitive, since there is much less magic going on, and things like the widgets and the module system really shine.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the "dojo.query(the_node)" wrapper trick (in a few dozen variations), but it didn't save the day.  I'm sure Dojo is a fine framework for certain situations.  If you're building a dynamic desktop application, which happens to run in a browser, then Dojo would be great.  But it's different in reverse... when you're just building a regular website, which happens to have some dynamic aspects.  There, the widget stuff is 5-6 MB of overkill, sitting on top of a core that isn't as intuitive as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The best reference you can get to a node, is the node itself including its id. 
At trigger time "this" is the node and with it you can get everything in particular its id with: this.id.

```
dojo.query(".anyClass").connect(Mouse.enter, function(evt){
   var xId=this.id;
   console.log("You entered element "+xId);
});
```